# Adding a Series of Increasing Numbers to an Existing Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm sure this is a very simple fix, but I want to add a column to my dataframe that counts from 0 to the end of the number of rows in increments of 15. For example for `df$fifteen`

```
fifteen
   0 
   15
   30
   45
```

Until the end of the dataframe that could be `n` rows long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`seq` should help here. Let's say you have dataframe 4 rows long.

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:4)
df$fifteen <- seq(0, by = 15, length.out = nrow(df))
df

#  a fifteen
#1 1       0
#2 2      15
#3 3      30
#4 4      45
```

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect. I had the sequencing but struggled with the legnth.out portion. I really appreciate the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
    mutate(fifteen = seq(0, by = 15, length.out = n()))
```